# England's ＆ English

Tags: grammar

When you want to convey countries possess things, will you say something like England's or English?
I've used "Taiwan's people" in my composition, and someone told me it was wrong because, after a country's name, it cannot be "'s". But later I saw "... that companies like Taiwan's Evergreen Marine" in one of my textbooks.
Thus, I think I have to come here and ask you guys.

Comment: ***England's people*** corresponds to ***Taiwan's people***, whereas ***English people*** corresponds with ***Taiwanese people***. Both forms are syntactically valid, and carry much the same meaning. But your example "Taiwan's Evergreen Marine" doesn't correspond to any valid English syntax (unless "Evergreen Marine" is the name of a Taiwanese company or similar organisation).

Comment: I think if there is a context for England and people, it is likely to be: The people of England.  Also, the people of Taiwan. "England's people" just sounds off to my ear, usage-wise.

Comment: @Lambie "Britain’s people, not its politicians, own the BBC" - [article](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/may/06/britain-politicians-bbc-programmes) in the _Guardian_ by Tony Hall (5 May 2016)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, it seems like Evergreen Marine is a company of Taiwan. Does that mean when it comes to object, "Taiwan's x" is valid; but when it comes to people, "Taiwan's x" is not?

Comment: You're overthinking it. Taiwan's people is correct, but it is uncommonly used (see other comments above). Use Tiawanese people unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Ok, thank you for answering.

Comment: Here's an example using both methods of indicating "possession / association" in the same utterance, which is perfectly okay: [*Sri Lanka has become an exporter of everything from underwear to football shirts for retailers such as **Zara of Spain** and **Britain's Marks and Spencer**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22spain+and+britain%27s+marks+and+spencer%22)

Comment: Thank you~~ @FumbleFingers